# How to send multiple packages together?

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock, winsock2

How to combine to send everything at once?

```
int data = 5;
int data2 = 15;
int data3 = 25;

sendto(sock, (char*)&data, sizeof data, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&ipAddr, sizeipAddr);
sendto(sock, (char*)&data2, sizeof data2, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&ipAddr, sizeipAddr);
sendto(sock, (char*)&data3, sizeof data3, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&ipAddr, sizeipAddr);
```

Comment: You could use an array of `int`s. But  you may have other problems if the sender and receiver use a different byte order for integers or have different sizes for `int`.

Comment: Create buffer yourself before or create `struct` to group the data?

Comment: If you are doing to learn how sockets work, that is fine. For larger scale messaging, use something like protocol buffers, flat buffers, capnproto, or thrift.

Comment: You might be interested in [`writev`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/writev).

Comment: @DavidRanieri ok but i like your example but i cant use it :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array and pass the address and size of the array:

```
int data[3] = {5, 15  25};

sendto(sock, (char*)&data[0], sizeof(data), 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&ipAddr, sizeipAddr);
```

But this is very bad style for sending data over a network. You have to take byte order and variable sizes into account.

Comment: This is what I need, thanks, the order of the figs with it. :)